# Populate a multidimensional array while looping

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an array declared above the beginning of a for loop as: `$array = array();`.
Now, in the for loop I start inserting values into it.
At some point I make one of its index as another array as `$array[$j]=array();`
And insert some values like, `$array[$j][$l] = id;` and so on.

Now, when I use `print_r($array);` inside the loop I get the expected value of the array.
But outside the loop this newly created array (2-D) is getting lost and I am getting only a 1-D array as an output.

Can someone please tell me where the problem could lie?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: It's likely you're using the same value for `$j` and thus overriding parts of your array (if I'm understanding the problem correctly).

Comment: @Strager: Thanks a lot for pointing out the problem. I was not able to find it, may be because i never thought that way. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code works properly. Perhaps you are switching your variables as strager suggests.

```
<?php
$array = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i+=1) {
    if ($i == 5) {
        $array[$i] = array('value 1', 'value 2');
    } else {
        $array[$i] = $i;
    }
}

print_r($array);
?>
```